# Class 'ZipArchive' not found phpexcel

Tags: codeigniter

Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /home/rm4r8egx5aq4/readyformove.in/application/libraries/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php

Comment: which server are you using?

Comment: which php version?

Answer (score 0):

**Check php zip extension is missing in your server or not.**

If yes,

Run the following commands in Linux Server.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip
sudo service apache2 restart
```

- *change php5.6-zip depend on your current PHP version.*

If it's Shared hosting, these links may help you.

https://in.godaddy.com/community/GoDaddy-Web-Hosting/PHP-Zip-Module/td-p/60228
https://in.godaddy.com/community/VPS-Dedicated-Servers/Error-when-installing-AbanteCart-for-eCommerce-site/m-p/2797#M121

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44PsYaM94K4

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to cPanel.
2. Locate Select PHP version and click on it.
3. Choose your desired PHP version and click on Set as Current.
4. To set the PHP extensions, Click on Switch to PHP settings.
5. Click on the extension you wish to change, enter the value and save the settings.